# how to remove an EmbeddedObject from a ListField?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, django-nonrel

I have this code:

class Member(models.Model):
    objects = MongoDBManager()

```
fav_members = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Member')) 

def del_fav_with_pymongo(self, fav):
    from pymongo import Connection
    from django.conf import settings

    conn = Connection(settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'])
    db = conn[settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']]

    db.base_member.update({"_id": ObjectId(self.id)}, {"$pull": {"fav_members": {"_id": ObjectId(fav.id)}}})

def del_fav_with_MongoDBManager(self, fav):

    Member.objects.raw_update({"_id": ObjectId(self.id)}, {"$pull": {"fav_members": {"_id": ObjectId(fav.id)}}})
```

Neither del_fav_with_pymongo() method, nor del_fav_with_MongoDBManager is pulling the fav.

Please anyone with the answer???

Comment: Can you post an example document?

Answer (score 0):

The mongo query you posted is correct - my guess is that because embedded objects don't have an _id field added by mongo the query hash given to pull isn't matching anything.

Can you use a specific attribute of fav?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the db you will see that EmbeddedModelField instances are not automatically given an _id. Use a specific attribute of `fav` to specify which to delete, or use the position index in the ListField.